# ERROR while loading world with DiffDrivePlugin as model plugin

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi there,
I'm trying to control a Pioneer2dx with *DiffDrivePlugin*.  Whenever I start the server, an error occurs. I got the plugin from [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/b60a5186d0008a915ccdc632f17df5d09ca33c24/plugins/DiffDrivePlugin.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default). No errors are coming while complilng.
Error:
**Error [Element.cc:671] Missing element description for [left_joint]

gzserver: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:648: typename boost::detail::sp_member_access::type boost::shared_ptr::operator->() const [with T = sdf::Element; typename boost::detail::sp_member_access::type = sdf::Element*]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.

Aborted**
What is this error and why this is coming? Can anyone provide me a solution?
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12191/error-while-loading-world-with-diffdriveplugin-as-model-plugin/) by [Anand George](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2345/anand-george/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-12-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2015-12-16**:
Can you post your world file, the command you are using to run gazebo, and the version of gazebo you are using?

**Comment by [Anand George](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2345/anand-george/) on 2015-12-16**:
Here is the world file: http://pastebin.com/q4urVZKq ;
Gazebo version 6.1.0 ;
command: gzserver -u test.world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You'll have to tell the diffdrive plugin about the joints in the model that the plugin should control. Here is  an example:

```
<include>
  <uri>model://pioneer2dx</uri>
  <plugin name="DiffDrivePlugin" filename="build/libDiffDrivePlugin.so">
    <left_joint>pioneer2dx::left_wheel_hinge</left_joint>
    <right_joint>pioneer2dx::right_wheel_hinge</right_joint>
  </plugin>
</include>
```

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anand George](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2345/anand-george/) on 2015-12-16**:
Still the same error is coming.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2015-12-16**:
I took a look at the pioneer2dx model, and it already loads the diff drive plugin: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/e024fe922c810f468e2a7ab277750354465478cd/pioneer2dx/model.sdf?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#model.sdf-175

**Comment by [Anand George](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2345/anand-george/) on 2015-12-16**:
So, I don't have to attach the plugin to the model. Therefore by publishing the required data to the topic ~/vel_cmd, canI control the robot? What data I have to publish?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2015-12-16**:
You should be able to. You can find out the type of message by using `gz topic -i /gazebo/default/vel_cmd`

**Comment by [Anand George](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2345/anand-george/) on 2015-12-16**:
It worked! Is there any method to move the robot to a location in the plane by specifying the coordinates?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2015-12-16**:
There is no built in method. You'll have to handle that computation yourself.

**Comment by [Anand George](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2345/anand-george/) on 2015-12-16**:
Okay thanks!!